# why are my rgeo / postgis distances so far off from reality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

I am trying to get the number of miles away a given post record...

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessor :lat, :lng
      set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:location, RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326))

      def distance_from(current_location)
        rgeo_factory.point(current_location[:lng], current_location[:lat]).distance(location) / 1.60934
      end 

    private

      def update_location!
        self.location = rgeo_factory.point(lng, lat) if lat && lng
      end

      def rgeo_factory
        Post.rgeo_factory_for_column(:location)
      end 

    end
```

If I create a post with a location of Las Vegas, NV (lat: 36.255123, lng: -115.238348), and I verify it--

```
1.9.3p125 :018 > p.lat = 36.255123
 => 36.255123 
1.9.3p125 :019 > p.lng = -115.238348
 => -115.238348
1.9.3p125 :019 > p    
#<Post id: 133, location: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x81d7130c "POINT (-115.238348 36.255123)">
```

when I try to get the distance between that post and a spot in california, I get an INSANE number of miles...

```
1.9.3p125 :027 > p.distance_from(:lat => 34.019454, :lng => -118.491191)
=> 240327.390598477
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure distance() returns km? Your conversion to miles seems to think so. The PostGIS native distance returns in meters. Is it possible the correct number of miles is about 240?

Answer (score 4):

The RGeo spherical factory does indeed return distance results in meters. Most coordinate systems work in meters (or some distortion thereof). If you want miles, you can multiply by a conversion factor (approx 0.000621371).